# How do you focus the image pattern on the CNN algorithm?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have an image of segmented black and white dots. (The white dots in this image show a certain pattern.) I want to send this image to the cnn algorithm. But I want the cnn algorithm to focus on these white points, how can I do this?

*Note : I'm building a CNN algorithm for classification.*

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the dots? segmenting them? Please consider adding a sample image.

Comment: White dots can be considered as tumors. I want to focus on white pixels.

Comment: Focus? with a microscope? We can't help you without sample image!

Comment: @Meisam [https://i.ibb.co/r5jkhGr/image.png[(https://i.ibb.co/r5jkhGr/image.png), this image has as many images. The objective's deep learning algorithm focuses on these white points

Comment: Your explanation is still not enough, but consider the fact, that the CNN model will ignore the black area by itself, so you just give the whole image as input to the model.